# How to read screen to see which pixels are white

Tags: iphone, ios, image-processing, screenshot

I have a view on which the user can draw some lines, which have been developed using [this](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#samplecode/GLEssentials/Listings/Classes_iOS_EAGLView_h.html).

Now the lines are drawn between points using the code:

```
- (void) renderLineFromPoint:(CGPoint)start toPoint:(CGPoint)end
{
    static GLfloat*     vertexBuffer = NULL;
    static NSUInteger   vertexMax = 64;
    NSUInteger          vertexCount = 0,
                        count,
                        i;

    //Allocate vertex array buffer
    if(vertexBuffer == NULL)
        vertexBuffer = malloc(vertexMax * 2 * sizeof(GLfloat));

    // Add points to the buffer so there are drawing points every X pixels
    count = MAX(ceilf(sqrtf((end.x - start.x) * (end.x - start.x) + (end.y - start.y) * (end.y - start.y)) / kBrushPixelStep), 1);
    for(i = 0; i < count; ++i) {
        if(vertexCount == vertexMax) {
            vertexMax = 2 * vertexMax;
            vertexBuffer = realloc(vertexBuffer, vertexMax * 2 * sizeof(GLfloat));
        }

        vertexBuffer[2 * vertexCount + 0] = start.x + (end.x - start.x) * ((GLfloat)i / (GLfloat)count);
        vertexBuffer[2 * vertexCount + 1] = start.y + (end.y - start.y) * ((GLfloat)i / (GLfloat)count);
        vertexCount += 1;
    }

    //Render the vertex array
    glVertexPointer(2, GL_FLOAT, 0, vertexBuffer);
    glDrawArrays(GL_POINTS, 0, vertexCount);

    // Display the buffer
    [self swapBuffers];
}
```

The objective is to read the drawing area of the screen which is initiated by the following code:

```
PictureView * scratchPaperView = [[RecordedPaintingView alloc] initWithFrame:CGRectMake(0, 45, 320, 415)];
    [self.view addSubview:scratchPaperView];
```

I want to find out the pixels of the lines, i.e. all the pixels that are white in the drawing area. Please tell me how to proceed from here?

Comment: you can try to read each pixel in the image and see if its white or other colour and on the basis of that you can differentiate your line from the screen which is white

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Assuming that you can get a UIImage.CGImage or a CGImageRef out of a PictureView, then you render this image into a CGBitMapContext. The image is going to tell you the number of components and if it has alpha and where alpa is. Most likely you are going to get 4 byte pixels (32 bits/pixel). You then walk each row looking at each pixel. Assuming a black background (which would be 255,0,0,0 or 0,0,0,255), you will see non-black pixels when you get close to or hit a line. A pure with pixel is going to be 255,255,255,255.

I'm pretty sure you can find examples of how to render an image into a context, and also how to examine pixels by googling around. Frankly what always gets me is the confusing pixel layout attributes - I usually end up printing a few test cases out to make sure I got it right.

Comment: Thanks, well I had to convert to image using glReadPixels and then convert them to an image and later process them, but once the image was there I managed to process it to achieve what I wanted.